# Recover files from encrypted Android MMC dump

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-recovery

A friend of mine gave me his Samsung Galaxy S2 (with Cyanogenmod 10.1.3 installed and Full Disk Encryption enabled) because it bootlooped.

I made a dump of mmcblk0 (the internal Flash memory) just for safety.
While dumping the phone died completely and now only shows the first bootscreen and doesn't go anywhere.

Now I am trying to recover everything possible from the flashdump but testdisk does only see 3 partitions:

```
GUID Partition Table (EFI)
Offset Sector: 0
Units are in 512-byte sectors

     Slot    Start        End          Length       Description
00:  Meta    0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   Safety Table
01:  -----   0000000000   0000008191   0000008192   Unallocated
02:  Meta    0000000001   0000000001   0000000001   GPT Header
03:  Meta    0000000002   0000000033   0000000032   Partition Table
04:  00      0000008192   0000049151   0000040960   
05:  -----   0000049152   0000106495   0000057344   Unallocated
06:  01      0000106496   0000311295   0000204800   
07:  -----   0000311296   0000344063   0000032768   Unallocated
08:  02      0000344064   0001392639   0001048576   
09:  -----   0001392640   0027419439   0026026800   Unallocated
```

Is there any way to find the encryption keys and decrypt the data that got copied to my PC before the phone died?